# Allowing the RegEx to start with a period or minus sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I've spent hours tring to find a solution. I have the following RegEx:

```
(?=.)^(([1-9][0-9]{0,8})|([0-9]))?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

I want to add the ability for the first character to match a minus sign but still match the rest of the stated RegEx.

```
I need these to work:
.0
.34
-.34
-30.0
-33.03
-34
-2

I need these to fail:
-04.4
043
3.
-
$34.33
1234567890.23
(any non-numeric character)
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the optional `-?` at the correct place should do the trick.

Also I'm fairly sure you don't need all these capturing groups (see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/rX5kS6/2)):

```
^-?(?=.)(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,8}|0)?(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$

^-?                   # optional leading -
(?=.)                 # followed by at least one character
(?:                   # non capturing group
    [1-9][0-9]{0,8}   # number without leading 0
|                     # or
    0                 # single 0
)?                    # integer part is optional
(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$    # decimal part
```

Comment: Thank you! This meets all the example data. I chose this answer because it was very close to the original RegEx and it has very good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
^-?(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,8}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|\.[0-9]{1,2})$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rX5kS6/3)

**EDIT:** If you want to allow `0.45` as valid input then use:

```
^-?(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,8}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|0*\.[0-9]{1,2})$
```

Comment: It's not explicitly stated in the question, but I believe it should also match `0.12`

Comment: OP didn't make it clear and had `[1-9]` in the regex shown so I went by that otherwise I would definitely allow `0.12` as valid input.

Comment: I believe the `|([0-9])` part of the regex is here to allow a single `0` while avoiding a `034` type of number. But on principle I agree, the rules should be enunciated more clearly in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This does work on all the example data that was provided. However, the "decimal" part feels repeated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
^(?:-[1-9.]{1}[0-9]*|\.|0\.)\.?[0-9]{0,2}$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qD2zZ7/2)

Comment: There is no lookbehind in Javascript

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the javascript tag. Will attempt to refactor.

Comment: Looks like I didn't need the look behind.